# How to include dependencies into an EAR without version in the file name

Tags: maven, dependencies

I am creating *.ear* using maven

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
  <configuration>
    <finalName>wsformatter-ear</finalName>
    <includeLibInApplicationXml>true</includeLibInApplicationXml>
    <version>1.4</version>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

All dependencies in the .ear look like **joda-time-1.6.2.jar**, **commons-io-1.4.jar** etc.

But also, I have dependencies, that I want have without version. For example, how can I do, that dependency **slf4j-api-1.5.6.jar** will look like **slf4j-api.jar** in my *.ear*

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: I have dependency of my another projects. Versions of that projects change very often

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you can't (without some kind of hacking on Maven's plugins' configuration) and even if you could - just don't. Maven approach and philosophy about dependencies is being strict and straight about them, including default convention of having version as file name suffix. It just immediately say which version of the artifact is used. If you depend on some artifact that is often released, you have to update its version in your EAR's POM anyway, so its "propagation" isn't somehow self-acting. Therefore, I don't see any problem with this file name suffix.

If this need for frequent change is problematic for you, maybe you should consider to modify somehow this frequently released artifact's development cycle? Probably you can extend a little a time it spend during same SNAPSHOT version? Even if you do frequent "internal" releases (like nightbuilds), Maven doesn't force you to bump your version every release (in sense of Maven Release Plugin). You can stay with some SNAPSHOT version as long as you want. Even in really quick Agile processes (or Kanban) this kind of "real" release usually happens every few weeks and it's long enough to be manageable.

At the end, it's not like this I won't help you (or something like this) or don't want to. I just think you're trying to go against Maven. Maven is really powerful if you accept and go with its approach and conventions. From my experience, trying to get around this means problems (sooner or later). I've already seen many projects that had Maven-like-Ant configuration and many developers around complaining that Maven sucks. After figuring out the stuff there I said them: "Maven doesn't suck, your POMs do".

Comment: One reason to do this is the following: The version numbers break <jar-file> references in the persistence.xml because they need to reference a concrete file name which is impossible to know with Maven dependency mediation (I cannot be sure that my other-1.0.0.jar will actually be part of the ear, maybe it is replaced by other-1.0.1.jar).

Answer (score 18):

I totally agree with Michal Kalinowski. But I fell into the same situation, well, actually an inverse situation - someone have configured the project to exclude the versions in the final EAR and I was looking for a way to cancel this, because it was against the maven's lifestyle, so I've searched in the web and found this very question, but the answer I found in the code itself. You can use:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
        <version>5</version>
    <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
    <fileNameMapping>no-version</fileNameMapping>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The line with the tag **fileNameMapping** is what you want. I hope this can help.